# Error with numpy.matrix() with python3.9.6

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np


def clean_input(row:list):
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if row[i] == " ":
            row[i] = "0"
    if len(row) != 9:
        for i in range(9-len(row)):
            row.append("0")
    return row


# row1 = input(f"{1}th Row: ")
# row2 = input(f"{2}th Row: ")
# row3 = input(f"{3}rd Row: ")
# row4 = input(f"{4}th Row: ")
# row5 = input(f"{5}th Row: ")
# row6 = input(f"{6}th Row: ")
# row7 = input(f"{7}th Row: ")
# row8 = input(f"{8}th Row: ")
# row9 = input(f"{9}th Row: ")

row1 = "34 53  3"
row2 = "  4 546 "
row3 = ""
row4 = " "
row5 = "5"
row6 = "      "
row7 = "123456789"
row8 = "000000000"
row9 = " 34 76657"


row_list = [
    list(row1), list(row2), list(row3), list(row4), list(row5),
    list(row6), list(row7), list(row8), list(row9)
]

print(np.matrix(row_list)) #line 40

clear_list = []
for element in row_list:
    clear_list.append(clean_input(element))
print(np.matrix(row_list)) #line 45
```

(python 3.9.6)

if you run above code you'll get an `numpy` error and again run same code just replace `print` statement(line 40`print(np.matrix(row_list))`) to line 45 or after `for` statment(line 43) every thing works fine.

i'm sure the `for` statement on line 43 isn't effecting the `row_list` on line 35. correct me if im wrong, happy to learn.

i dont know its `Python` problem or anything to with `numpy`.

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

if `print(np.matrix(row_list))` statement on line 40

```
chitti@Thor /m/4/F/L/Py_files> python3 sudoku.py
/home/chitti/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py:145:
VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple
of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, 
you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
arr = N.array(data, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
[[list(['3', '4', ' ', '5', '3', ' ', ' ', '3'])
  list([' ', ' ', '4', ' ', '5', '4', '6', ' ']) 
  list([]) 
  list([' '])
  list(['5'])
  list([' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '])
  list(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'])
  list(['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'])
  list([' ', '3', '4', ' ', '7', '6', '6', '5', '7'])]]
```

if `print(np.matrix(row_list))` statement on line 45 or after `for` statement
everything works fine

```
chitti@Thor /m/4/F/L/Py_files> python3 sudoku.py
[['3' '4' '0' '5' '3' '0' '0' '3' '0']
 ['0' '0' '4' '0' '5' '4' '6' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['5' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9']
 ['0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0' '0']
 ['0' '3' '4' '0' '7' '6' '6' '5' '7']]
```

**Photos**

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLLSQ.png): `print(np.matrix(row_list))` statement on line 40

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3Ngb.png): `print(np.matrix(row_list))` statement on line 45

Comment: I couldn't understand what is your goal. The code is running without any problem; only a warning not error. The 'for' statement pass the row_list from function "clean_input" and changes the row_list (print it after 'for' statement to see the changes). it is obvious the results of line 40 will be as it is shown in the run window; the rows are only listed in line 35 and there is not any operation done on it until 'for' statement.

Comment: At 40, `row_list` is a list of lists the vary in length.  You can't make a proper 2d array from such a list.  The **warning** tells you that you'll get 1d array of list (it's better to use `np.array` instead of `np.matrix`). `clean_input` is poorly written (`row` and `element` are the same object list), but never the less does modify the `row_list` lists in-place.  You aren't trying to do anything difficult; you just haven't taken enough care in writing and testing this code.

Comment: `np.matrix` is deprecated. Use `np.array`.

Comment: @Ali_Sh there is no goal here, the thing is i dont understand that how `for` statement is affecting list `row_list` im sure im iterating through list, and appending to another list. am i missing any logic here, its been long since i coded

Comment: @hpaulj yeah `clean_input` is written poorly, my bad, i changed it now, and now it raised one more prob in my small brain how the hell this function is even working without an error when `element` is not even declared in the scoop but it executed `
def clean_input(row:list):
    for i in range(len(row)):
        if row[i] == " ":
            row[i] = "0"
    if len(element) != 9:
        for i in range(9-len(element)):
            element.append("0")
    return row`

Comment: @hpaulj and one more thing is as i mention before to @Ali_Sh how `row_list` being effected, im not even passing it to any function just iterating through it. am i missing any `python` logic here, explain me if you could, thanks!

Comment: `element` is the iteration variable, and thus a global for the function that's from inside the loop.

Comment: Hi @Reigns, if any answer has solved your question or was helpful please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark or upvoting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
row1 = "34 53  3" 
row2 = "  4 546 "
row3 = ""
row4 = " "
row5 = "5"
row6 = "      "
row7 = "123456789"
row8 = "000000000"
row9 = " 34 76657"

row_list = [list(row1), list(row2), list(row3), list(row4), list(row5), 
list(row6), list(row7), list(row8), list(row9)]

print(np.matrix(row_list))
```

You are trying to declare a 2d matrix from varying length lists. That's why you are facing the error. In any matrix, all the rows and columns must have the same number of values. You can solve your problem by resizing all your rows to similar length by intializing empty places with an arbitrary value i.e (0/-1).

Comment: Thanks man for your time. But what i'm after is different, trying to say one thing getting another with my worst English. I hope you'll understand my prob from my `comments` in @Ali_sh `answer`

Answer (score 0):

As @hpaulj mentioned the reason, in your code, *row* is the same as *element*. Your function modifies rows, which are indeed the elements of the `row_list`, by using `row[i] = ...`. `row[i] = ...` will changes the imported arg. The elements are passing through the function which modifies them. Your code is processing as the following example:

```
import numpy as np
row_list = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 5, 4], [7, 8, 9]]
clear_list = []
for element in row_list:
    element[1] = 0
    clear_list.append(element)
print(np.matrix(row_list))
```

which will result in `[[1 0 3] [3 0 4] [7 0 9]]`. As it is obvious, the elements are modified.
One way to prevent `row_list` from modification is to copy it; some codes like:

```
import copy
r_l = copy.deepcopy(row_list)
for element in r_l:
    clear_list.append(clean_input(element))
```

Comment: `a = "abcde"`

`for element in a:`
    `if element == "c":`
        `element = 'see'` 
    `print(element)`

`print(a)`

**output** `a b see d e abcde`


`row_list = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`

`for element1 in row_list:`
    `if element1[1] == 5:`
        `element1[1] = "five"`
    `print(element1)`

`print(row_list)` **output** `[1, 2, 3] [4, 'five', 6] [7, 8, 9] [[1, 2, 3], [4, 'five', 6], [7, 8, 9]]`  if you look at this code example the `a` isn't effected by a first `for` statement but the `row_list` is by second `for` statement.  Is it how `list` behaves in python?

Comment: im just learing python, noob. your help is much appreciate and sorry for my english

Comment: [photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ojy1UJXRoYbQDco__iGgPKZgk58zIaX6/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Dear @CharanReigns, `element` is an independent variable but `element[i]` is an assignment statement. It is the main difference between them. As you could see it in your new examples in the comment, the second example changes the original list or string because it uses assignment statement in it. only, use code lines as `element1[i]` just for where you need to modify the original list or ... .

Comment: Otherwise, use a copy of the original list as I gave the example or correct the function `clean_input` as @hpaulj wrote in his answer. Hope my answer clarified it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the original function:

```
In [18]: def clean_input(row:list):
    ...:     for i in range(len(row)):
    ...:         if row[i] == " ":
    ...:             row[i] = "0"
    ...:     if len(element) != 9:
    ...:         for i in range(9-len(element)):
    ...:             element.append("0")
    ...:     return row

In [20]: row_list
Out[20]: 
[['3', '4', ' ', '5', '3', ' ', ' ', '3'],
 [' ', ' ', '4', ' ', '5', '4', '6', ' '],
 [],
 [' '],
 ['5'],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 [' ', '3', '4', ' ', '7', '6', '6', '5', '7']]
```

These lists were created by applying `list` to a string:

```
In [22]: list(row1)
Out[22]: ['3', '4', ' ', '5', '3', ' ', ' ', '3']
```

Let's apply `clean_input` to one element of the list:

```
In [24]: clean_input(row_list[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-24-4232fb255666>", line 1, in <module>
    clean_input(row_list[0])
  File "<ipython-input-18-d419d4f2ec88>", line 5, in clean_input
    if len(element) != 9:
NameError: name 'element' is not defined

In [25]: row_list[0]
Out[25]: ['3', '4', '0', '5', '3', '0', '0', '3']
```

The first loop that replaces " " in the `row` with '0'`worked.  The list was passed by-reference to the function, and the`row[i]=...` changes the list in-place.

The loop referencing `element` does not work because the variable `element` is not defined.

But in a loop `for element in row_list():` that variable is defined and the loop works.  Or doing that assignment 'manually':

```
In [26]: element = row_list[4]
In [27]: element
Out[27]: ['5']
In [28]: clean_input(element)
Out[28]: ['5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
In [29]: row_list[4]
Out[29]: ['5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

`clean_input` does return the changed list, but it has also changed the list as it was passed.

Cleaning up the function a bit:

```
In [30]: def clean_input(row:list):
    ...:     for i in range(len(row)):
    ...:         if row[i] == " ":
    ...:             row[i] = "0"
    ...:     for i in range(9-len(row)):
    ...:         row.append("0")
    ...:     return row
    ...:
```

If we pass a copy of the list, then the original is not changed:

```
In [31]: clean_input(row_list[1].copy())
Out[31]: ['0', '0', '4', '0', '5', '4', '6', '0', '0']
In [32]: row_list[1]
Out[32]: [' ', ' ', '4', ' ', '5', '4', '6', ' ']
```

and put in a list comprehension, we get a new list of lists:

```
In [33]: new_list = [clean_input(row.copy()) for row in row_list]
In [34]: new_list
Out[34]: 
[['3', '4', '0', '5', '3', '0', '0', '3', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '4', '0', '5', '4', '6', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 ['0', '3', '4', '0', '7', '6', '6', '5', '7']]
In [35]: row_list
Out[35]: 
[['3', '4', '0', '5', '3', '0', '0', '3'],
 [' ', ' ', '4', ' ', '5', '4', '6', ' '],
 [],
 [' '],
 ['5', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
 ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
 ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'],
 [' ', '3', '4', ' ', '7', '6', '6', '5', '7']]
```

The function could be streamlined a bit further with:

```
In [50]: def clean_input(row:list):
    ...:     row1 = ['0' if i==' ' else i for i in row]
    ...:     row1.extend(['0']*(9-len(row1)))
    ...:     return row1
```

This makes a new list, so we don't have to pass a copy.  That's a cleaner approach.

```
In [51]: clean_input(row_list[1])
Out[51]: ['0', '0', '4', '0', '5', '4', '6', '0', '0']
```

Replacing space with 0 could have done on the original string:

```
In [56]: list(row2.replace(' ','0'))
Out[56]: ['0', '0', '4', '0', '5', '4', '6', '0']
```

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj for clarification. Im just making a Sudoku solver and I want to cleanup user input. I know I can lookup on internet for easy solutions but I want to do it myself, on the process THIS things are happening. Needless to say I'm learning new things. Have a good day. :)

Comment: I got it, so in `clean_input` func the `element` is not defined but in `for` loop at bottom of the code I declared `element`  ( `for element in ...`  ). So basically when the func `clean_input` called inside  `for element in ...` loop it (`clean_input`) took that `for` loop's `element` as a reference. Right?